# The fastest way to split uint64 into two others by digit position

Tags: go, bit-shift, decimal-point

I have a function like:

```
func splitNumberByDecimals(u uint256, dec uint) (intFraction, decFraction uint){

 ...

 }
```

The task is to extract an unsigned number, and the number of decimal places for this number. And based on these decimals, split number into two others and return them.

Example:

```
num         = 123456
dec         = 100
intFraction = 123
decFraction = 456
```

It`s like divide a number by decimals and return the integer part and the remainder as uint:

```
123456/100 = 123,456
```

The problem is that I'm working with custom uint types whose size is 256bit. In addition, this function should be very lightweight. I can't use string casting or anything like that because it's very heavy. Is there some kind of bitwise algorithm that can be applied to this problem?

Comment: Your example uses `dec = 1000` not `100`. Btw as its name says: _bitwise_ operations operate on bits, which is the binary representation. What you want is the decimal representation, and since `10` is not a power of `2` (decimal and binary), this can't be solved with bitwise operations.

Comment: Does this work for you? `intFraction = u / dec` and `decFraction = u % dec`

Comment: @icza Yeah, you right, dec = 1000. Thanks.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic, two dividing of big uint, is not good for me in this case. But if there is no way, what to do)
Thanks.

Comment: If division is bottleneck of your algorithm, you must be doing billions of divisions. Seems like a good cause for parallelization.

Comment: @JobWeek: Think about what you're asking here. A number doesn't have digits, it's only when you format that number into a representation given some base does it have digits. Computers store numbers as base-2, so if you want to split up that number by base-10 factors, then you need to do that math exactly like if you were formatting the number in a string. In most cases `strconv.FormatInt` will be plenty fast, but you may be able to skip an extra copy and some other ops for your version which doesn't need every individual digit in a string

Comment: I wonder your performance standard and why handling string is slow